# Sending a request from website to mobile and getting back a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, messaging

I have created a sign up page to create a user and then login using the credentials.But i want only those user can login which are approved by Admin.For approval i wanted a request to be send to admin's mobile when user made sign up request then according the response of Admin, a message about approval status should be send on user mobile number.
I dont want to create android app for this. Is there any other method for this?

A method that make YES/NO request to mobile,then on mobile receiving the request then admin make a response (approved or rejected) and at last according to response sending a approval status to user mobile number.

Comment: I’ve only seen this done by email.  User signs up, admin gets an email.

Comment: @James Sir ,But with email how do we send back a response to server to update the approval status of user ?

Comment: Put a link in the email?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple webapp with browser Notification Api (but this requires that your web app is active on your browser)
And use it to be notified when user try to login.

I think this is the only acceptable method without creating a real mobile app with external notification system (like firebase).

Else you can create a simple android app integrated with firebase and use it to receive notification and do your action with firebase realtimeDb or something like that.

Comment: So creating App or web app for notification is the only two ways right? Can it be done using Email or Whatapp?

Comment: yes of course, you can use email to send notification with a link to your webapp where you can approve or denied the action. But in any way you need to have exposed "Endpoint" or somthing like that to send your action to your api.